# Linux LUKS and choice of filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, luks

Which filesystem displays the best performance when running on a LUKS encrypted partition? Does it make sense to use f2fs when the LUKS partition is on an SSD, or does the device-mapper abstraction render f2fs's SSD optimizations useless?

Answer (score 8):

There is lots of advice, but very few empirical results for the efficiency of
using encryption.

I found one such study :
[SSD Linux benchmarking: Comparing filesystems and encryption methods](https://www.mayrhofer.eu.org/ssd-linux-benchmark).
In the table below, the measures are real/user/sys and the best results are
colored green while the worst are colored in red:

[[image: click for a larger image]click for a larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zTvA.jpg)

Based on these results, the author has decided on using dm-crypt in
aes-xts-plain mode with 128 Bit keylength and btrfs with ssd alignment and
`compress=lzo`.

Another useful article is
[The Performance Impact Of Linux Disk Encryption On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_1404_encryption&num=5).
It studied the CPU usage during installation on the three configurations of
stock install options (no disk encryption), full disk-encryption method using LUKS on LVM and eCryptfs-based home directory encryption.
The results are summarized in the graph below, and the conclusion is
that the install without encryption averaged 26%,
while the LUKS on LVM and eCryptfs encryption both averaged about 30~31%,
so are both almost equivalent in performance.

[[image: click for a large image]click for a larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS4py.jpg)

An article that has no empirical results but lots of good advice is
[LinuX, SSDs and disk encryption](http://blog.mfhs.eu/2013/09/15/linux-ssds-and-disk-encryption/).
I recommend reading this article, and here is the main advice given:

1. For SSD partition you should at least add the mount options `noatime` and `nodiratime` to suppress the bookkeeping of access times for files and directories.
2. Set up ramdisks using tmpfs for temporary files.
3. Change the disk scheduler to use [noop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noop_scheduler) or [deadline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadline_scheduler).
4. Enable device-level write cache
5. Parameter the browser so as not to use a disk cache.

Answer (score 6):

I did some testing with a low-to-middle end system. Results below.

[image: table]

In conclusion, it seems that encryption doesn't render a filesystem's optimizations useless. As you can see in the table, for dmcrypt/LUKS (AES256), the `F2FS` filesystem was faster than `EXT4` in almost all scenarions in which it was faster by default (without encryption, that is). Somewhat surprisingly, it also provided a noticeable benefit in cases where it woulnd't without encryption - namely, the `Bonnie++ Sequential Output (Per char)` and the `Flexible I/O Tester Sequential Read` tests.

For this same scenario it was also slower in two tests (Sequential Write - Bonnie++ and FIO), but not *much* slower anyway. Your mileage may vary.

I didn't test EXT4 with AES-128bits because of limited time since it'd not be essential for this answer.

*Note: I observed very big, weird deviations in testing with AES-128bits. Up to 15% variations in most tests, and even 37% (!) in one case. Not sure why. I didn't use the system for anything else for the duration of the tests. <s>The system (root) is itself encrypted with AES-256, so I can think of an hypothetical explanation involving CPU pipelines/opcache, but... Really can't tell just yet.</s> (This also happens when testing from a live CD, without ever unlocking the AES-256bit partition, so that's not the reason).*

Deviation was kept under 3,6% (1,4% typical) everywhere else. I'm adopting a 4% error margin. Thus, differences smaller than 4% should be ignored for these results.

Test setup:

```
SSD: Kingston SV300S37A/120G
Mainboard: ASUS Sabertooth 990FX R2.0
CPU: AMD FX-6350 @ stock
Kernel version: 4.11.3
IO Scheduler: CFQ
All tests were run using an 80GB secondary partition.
```

Table of results in ASCII format (differences deemed "irrelevant" are omitted):

```
                                                                                                                |+===================================+| 
                                                                                                                ||            % Change               ||
                                      |+=====================+=====================+=================+|         ||--------+--------+--------+--------||
                                      ||   (no encryption)   |       AES-256       |    AES-128      ||         ||   F2FS / EXT4   |Crypto / NoCrypto||
|+============+========================+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+----------||=========||--------+--------+--------+--------+|
|| Test suite | Test Method            | EXT4     | F2FS     | EXT4     | F2FS     | EXT4 | F2FS     || Unit    ||nocrypto| aes256 | aes128 | aes256 ||
|+------------+------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+----------++---------++--------+--------+--------+--------+|
|| Manual     | Read                   | 390.6    | 391.59   | 320      | 325.6    | -    | 345.36   || MiB/s   ||        |        | -11.81 | -16.85 ||
||(cp and dd) | Write (zeros)          | 501.96   | 517.17   | 96.9     | 96.7     |      | 112.16   || MiB/s   ||        |        | -78.31 | -81.30 ||
||            | Write (random data)    | 100.44   | 97.99    | 91.8     | 89.5     |      | 97.64    || MiB/s   ||        |        |        | -08.66 ||
||--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------||--------|--------|--------|--------||
||            | Seq. Output – Per char | 80.68    | 83.76    | 63.56    | 80.59    | -    | 75.56    || MiB/s   ||        | +26.79 | -09.79 |        ||
||            | Seq. Output – Block    | 498.92   | 492.42   | 104.74   | 101.13   |      | 90.9     || MiB/s   ||        |        | -81.54 | -79.46 ||
|| Bonnie++   | Seq. Output – Rewrite  | 196.4    | 198.99   | 74.69    | 70.8     |      | 70.27    || MiB/s   ||        | -05.21 | -64.69 | -64.42 ||
||            | Seq. Input - Per char  | 86.93    | 86.04    | 84.01    | 81.25    |      | 87.84    || MiB/s   ||        |        |        | -05.57 ||
||            | Seq. Input – Block     | 352.57   | 355.99   | 286.36   | 289.24   |      | 304.5    || MiB/s   ||        |        | -14.46 | -18.75 ||
||            | Random seeks           | 9452.9   | 9102.2   | 8142.3   | 8224.8   |      | 7431.4   || ops/s   ||        |        | -18.36 | -09.64 ||
||--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------||--------|--------|--------|--------||
|| Fs-mark    | 1000 files, 1 thread   | 193.7    | 236.6    | 93.6     | 103.7    | -    | 73.9     || files/s || +18.13 | +10.79 | -68.77 | -56.17 ||
||            | 5000 files, 4 threads  | 310.1    | 348.8    | 90.9     | 99       |      | 91.6     || files/s || +11.10 | +08.91 | -73.74 | -71.62 ||
||--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------||--------|--------|--------|--------||
||            | Random read            | 56.77    | 69.86    | 58.79    | 63.51    |      | 61.93    || MiB/s   ||        |        |        |        ||
||            |                        | 14188    | 17461    | 14695    | 15874    |      | 15479    || IOPS    || +23.07 | +08.02 | -11.35 | -09.09 ||
|| Flexible   |                        |          |          |          |          | -    |          ||         ||        |        |        |        ||
|| I/O        | Random write           | 59.91    | 78.99    | 52.2     | 63.75    |      | 67.75    || MiB/s   ||        |        |        |        ||
|| Tester     |                        | 14973    | 19745    | 13046    | 15935    |      | 16934    || IOPS    || +31.87 | +22.14 | -14.24 | -19.30 ||
||            |                        |          |          |          |          |      |          ||         ||        |        |        |        ||
||            | Sequential read        | 284.02   | 247.57   | 95.14    | 95.17    |      | 95.98    || MiB/s   ||        |        |        |        ||
||            |                        | 71001    | 61889    | 23781    | 23788    |      | 23991    || IOPS    || -12.83 |        | -61.24 | -61.56 ||
||            |                        |          |          |          |          |      |          ||         ||        |        |        |        ||
||            | Sequential write       | 94.06    | 100.77   | 100.63   | 96.56    |      | 86.93    || MiB/s   ||        |        |        |        ||
||            |                        | 23512    | 25188    | 25153    | 24137    |      | 21728    || IOPS    || +07.13 | -04.04 | -13.74 | -04.17 ||
|+------------+------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+----------++---------++--------+--------+--------+--------+|
_
```